# Can I append specific values from one array to another?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, append, indices

I have successfully imported a CSV file into a multi-dimensional array in python. What I want to do now is pick specific values from the array and put them into a new single array. For instance if my current arrays were:

```
[code1, name1, number 1]
[code2, name2, number 2]
```

I want to select only the code1 and code 2 values and insert them into a new array, because I need to compare just those values to a user input for validation. I have tried using the following:

```
newvals=[]
newvals.append oldvals([0],[0])
```

where newvals is the new array for just the codes, oldvals is the original array with all the data and the index [0],[0] refers to code 1, but I'm getting a syntax error. I can't use any add ons as they will be blocked by my admin.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that shows what you're doing and a stack trace of the error you get.

Answer (score 0):

```
newvals = []
for i in oldvals:
    newvals.append(i[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can get the first Element in an array `a` with `a[0]`.
You can create a new array based on another by using the "[array for in](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)" syntax

```
oldData = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
newData = [x[0] for x in oldList]
# newData is now [1,4]
```